# Pasar datos de un addEventListener a otro

Tags: javascript, html5

mi duda es la siguiente:

Cómo podría pasar una variable que se está ejecutando en un addEventListener a otro, en la variable **index** estoy guardando un dato, este se encuentra en **validarDivision.addEventListener** y me gustaría pasarlo al segundo que lleva por nombre **validarClient.addEventListener**, pero quisiera saber de que forma lo podría realizar.

el código es el siguiente:

```js
let validarDivision = document.querySelector('#selectDiv')
let validarClient = document.querySelector('#selectClient')

//addEventListener 1
validarDivision.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let index = validarDivision.selectedIndex; //variable que quiero pasar al otro addEventListener
    let valor = validarDivision.value;
    console.log('Division: ' + index + ' ' + valor);
})

//addEventListener 2
validarClient.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let index2 = validarClient.selectedIndex;
    let valor2 = validarClient.value;
    console.log('Cliente: ' + index2 + ' ' + valor2);

})
```

Comment: Declara la variable fuera del listener: `let index;` y luego dentro le asignas el valor, sin declaración: `index = validarDivision.selectedIndex;` Así, podrás usarla en cualquier ámbito.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvió bastante tu respuesta!!! :) 
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes declarar la variable fuera del listener y luego dentro le asignas el valor, sin declaración. Así, podrás usarla en cualquier ámbito.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let validarDivision = document.querySelector('#selectDiv')
let validarClient = document.querySelector('#selectClient')
let valor;

//addEventListener 1
validarDivision.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let index = validarDivision.selectedIndex; //variable que quiero pasar al otro addEventListener
  valor = validarDivision.value;
  console.log(`Division:  ${index} ${valor}`);
})

//addEventListener 2
validarClient.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let index2 = validarClient.selectedIndex;
  let valor2 = validarClient.value;
  console.log(`Cliente: ${index2} ${valor2} \nY el valor que tomó en el otro listener es: ${valor}`);

})
```

```html
<select id="selectDiv">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--Seleccione--</option>
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<select id="selectClient">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--Seleccione Cliente--</option>
  <option value="c1">Client 1</option>
  <option value="c2">Client 2</option>
  <option value="c3">Client 3</option>
</select>
```

O bien, dado que tienes una referencia de ambos elementos, puedes obtener el valor del elemento seleccionado del otro `select` usando esa referencia.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let validarDivision = document.querySelector('#selectDiv')
let validarClient = document.querySelector('#selectClient')

//addEventListener 1
validarDivision.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let index = validarDivision.selectedIndex; //variable que quiero pasar al otro addEventListener
  let valor = validarDivision.value;
  console.log(`Division:  ${index} ${valor}`);
})

//addEventListener 2
validarClient.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let index2 = validarClient.selectedIndex;
  let valor2 = validarClient.value;
  /*Este es el valor del otro select*/
  let otherValue = validarDivision.options[validarDivision.selectedIndex].value;

  console.log(`Cliente: ${index2} ${valor2} \nY el valor del otro select es: ${otherValue}`);

})
```

```html
<select id="selectDiv">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--Seleccione--</option>
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<select id="selectClient">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>--Seleccione Cliente--</option>
  <option value="c1">Client 1</option>
  <option value="c2">Client 2</option>
  <option value="c3">Client 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte así me queda mucho más claro! :D